# Rufus scheduler not logging in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, passenger, rufus-scheduler

My rails app kicks off a process with rufus-scheduler in an initializer. Here's a stripped-down version of the initializer's code:

```
# config.logger isn't available here, so we have to grab it from the Rails object
logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER

logger.warn(Time.now.to_s + ": Starting Rufus Scheduler")

# run every Wednesday at 10 AM 
cron_string = '0 10 * * 3'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
scheduler.cron cron_string do
  logger.warn(Time.now.to_s + ": Starting Background Process")
  (do work here)
  logger.warn(Time.now.to_s + ": Finished Background Process")
end

logger.warn(Time.now.to_s + ": Rufus Scheduler set Background Process to run with the following cron string: [#{cron_string}]")
```

In all environments, the code runs like a champ. The populate process does its thing and finishes gracefully. The problem, however, is with logging. When RAILS_ENV is set to "production", the messages inside the cron block don't log at all.

I'm using Passenger 2.2.9 and Rails 2.3.5. I figure one of these two things is preventing the process from logging. Can anyone tell me which it is and how to get it to log in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found the problem, thanks to this article: http://earthcode.com/blog/2009/05/rails_script_runner_logging_cron.html

Turns out the logger will not auto-flush in production. So, I just added

```
logger.flush
```

to the end of the process and BANG everything worked.