# Debugging Rufus scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I am doing this in my Rails console:

```
job = scheduler.at 1.minute.from_now do Service.log.debug 'scheduler works' end
job.schedule_info
=> Wed, 07 Aug 2013 16:14:46 UTC 00:00
```

`scheduler` is defined in other file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

def scheduler
  @scheduler ||= Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
end
```

And when I run in console:

```
Service.log.debug 'scheduler works'
```

Service log file is written.

## Problem

```
scheduler.at 1.minute.from_now do Service.log.debug 'scheduler works' end
```

Does not write in the log after a minute. What am I missing? How could I debug this?

## Actual problem

I have a server in EC2 that seems is shutdown and scheduled tasks are not run.

Thing is that in my development environment I test with a task running in one minute and it works. This is in server not in console. In console, as I mentioned is failing.

## Dev environment

ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]

Thin 1.5.0

## Remote environment

ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]

apache2 2.2.22

passenger 4.0.5

## Gems

rails 3.2.8

rufus-scheduler 2.0.18

Comment: What's different from your development environment in your EC2 environment. On what kind of server do you run Rails (in dev and in EC2)? Are you sure the process holding the scheduler doesn't terminate (and requests are processed by forked processes?

Comment: I think could be log flushing, what is occurring to me now is to execute a piece of code I can clearly see, but I have no ideas which code. How could I know scheduler process don't terminate?

Comment: If it's an issue with log flushing, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210561/rufus-scheduler-not-logging-in-production?rq=1

Comment: Have it write to a file... Have it use something else than your log system...

Comment: I am using this to test: `echo "each time" >> ~/some_file`, no luck yet.

Comment: See that problem in remote server occurs from rails console in local env too...

Comment: Sorry, there is no "echo" in my Ruby (1.9.3 p392 on Debian GNU/Linux).

Comment: So what are you running your Rails on?

Comment: I meant unix command with back quotes  `\`echo "each time" >> ~/some_file \`` In local this works....

Comment: Passenger, Unicorn, Webrick? Same on dev and EC2?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux] in remote, ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0] in local.

Comment: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: Am I bad reporting my problem?

Comment: Yes. You can't seem to answer to:

* what is different from your dev env to your ec2 env?
* what server are you running Rails on top of? (Webrick, Passenger, Unicorn, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

That's a classic:

https://groups.google.com/group/rufus-ruby/search?group=rufus-ruby&q=passenger&pli=1
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rufus-ruby/passenger (new google groups)

(unfortunately, most of the links in those discussions are dead (4 years ago...))

You'll have to check your Passenger configuration to see how it behaves. You'll have to make sure the process where the rufus-scheduler thread is started is preserved somehow.

Take the time to read the Passenger configuration / manual and experiment tuning it.

I vaguely remember that those could help:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerPoolIdleTime
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMinInstances

Ajet's answer in [Rufus Scheduler not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641122/rufus-scheduler-not-running) is interesting, he advocates:

```
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMinInstances 1
```

Comment: I have this in apache conf: `# Do not restart application nor spawner
PassengerPoolIdleTime 0
PassengerMaxPreloaderIdleTime 0` anyway, I will read. Just posting, in case is helpful

Comment: first link has a redirect loop for me

Comment: Works fine for me, here is a more modern version of it though: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rufus-ruby/passenger

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the ["PassengerSpawnMethod direct" setting](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerSpawnMethod) in my Apache VirtualHost for my Dashing application (which uses rufus-scheduler) to get it to work correctly.