# rufus cron job not working in Apache/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, linode, rufus-scheduler

I have a Rails app running on Apache/Passenger. It has a rufus-scheduler cron job that runs in the background and sends out notifications via email.

When I am running the app in development on the WEBrick server, the emails are sent like they are supposed to be sent.

When I start up the app in production on Apache/Passenger, the emails don't get sent. In the production logs it doesn't show any logs for rufus-scheduler.

I'm stuck in this problem. Your help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108719/debugging-rufus-scheduler

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to set `PassengerSpawnMethod` to `direct`. The Phusion Passenger documentation explains why this solves it: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#spawning_methods_explained
In particular, take a look at section "15.4. Smart spawning gotcha #2: the need to revive threads".

Comment: Thanks Hongli for your valuable answer,but i have solved my issue by using cronic gem. url:- https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Comment: Hi, where I have to set PassengerSpawnMethod property, I am using standalone installation of Passenger 5 in Ubuntu environment.

Comment: "passenger start --spawn-method direct" can you help solve this issue

Comment: This link helped me a lot to understand the spwaning methods: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/