# Rails - Passenger and Nginx preventing rufus-scheduler from scheduling in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rufus-scheduler

I am using Rufus Scheduler to call a function once every 2 minutes.

In development mode when running rufus scheduler with WEBrick the system works as expected and my function is called every 2 minutes.

When I deploy to our production server which runs passenger and NGINX the scheduler does not call the function anymore.

I am assuming this is to do with threads, with the scheduler running on a separate thread that might be getting destroyed on our production server.

I have seen answers for similar issues when using Passenger and Apache together, but I am unable to come up with a solution for running rufus scheduler with passenger and NGINX in production mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code below setting up rufus

```
# :nocov:
require 'rufus-scheduler'
include TwitterParser
unless ENV['NODAEMON'] || Rails.env != 'production'
  scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
  TwitterParser.set_up

  scheduler.every '2m' do
    begin
      TwitterParser.parse_tweets
    rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
      puts 'Too Many Twitter requests, resets in: ' + error.rate_limit.reset_in.to_s
    end
  end
end
# :nocov:
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the rufus-scheduler FAQ.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#faq

It contains links to (old) articles about Passenger + rufus-scheduler

Amog them, this SO answer by one of the authors of Passenger might help:

[rufus cron job not working in Apache/Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861387/rufus-cron-job-not-working-in-apache-passenger#answer-21868555)

Have a good time.